# Lightning tree grid component adding two icons in one column

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hello is there a way to add two icons in single column in lightning tree grid component?
I am having a requirement to add asterisk(required) field and an icon with label side by side. I also took a look at creating custom data type as lightning datatable does. But seems like it only works in data table.
Has somebody resolved such requirement?

Answer (score 0):

> ... is there a way to add two icons in single column in lightning tree grid component?

"Icons" as in "unicode character": Yes, no probs! Just define your column as text...

```json
{
    type: 'text',
    fieldName: 'iconic',
    label: 'Iconic',
    initialWidth: 50,
},
...
```

... and populate the column...

```json
{
    iconic: '   ★',
    ....
}
```

"Icons" as in HTML (or even LWC) elements? Not really!